# Python - Open .bat file in new window and also interact with it

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I am trying to run a `.bat` file in a new window so the user of the PC can input commands, however I want to also be able to programatically input commands at the same time. Is this possible? I have been fiddling around with `subprocess` and `Popen` however I havn't been able to get anything to work.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your question right, you are looking for something like this:

```
subprocess.Popen("start your_file_name.bat", shell=True)
```

It opens a new cmd window and runs your .bat file in it while the python code runs forward.

Comment: Great, that worked! How can I now send commands to this window?